# Inputenc Error:

Tags: input-encodings

```
% LinearAlgebra.tex

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get this inputenc error:

Unicode Character ^^T (U+14) not set up for use with latex.

It seems to indicate that this Unicode Character is just after the:

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
```

Any suggestions on how to approach solving this `inputenc` error since there does not seem to be anything beyond `{stackengine}`.

Comment: You've probably got a dodgy character in your input: in the first instance, try retyping just those lines manually in a clean file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.